# .htaccess 301 redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I switched my website from MODx to Wordpress to a different platform so now I have to make a 301 redirect.

All I need to do is to 301 Redirect `http://www.domain.com/page-name.html` to `http://www.domain.com/page-name/`.

What lines should I add to my Wordpress `.htaccess` file?

.htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For just one page, try:

```
Redirect 301 /page-name.html /page-name/
```

For everything ending with html, try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^.]+)\.html$ /$1/
```

Comment: It works but my only problem is that is breaks the homepage of my Wordpress website.

Comment: @Andrei What's your homepage's URL?

Comment: It's a index.php file. I've updated the .htaccess file content in the original post

Comment: Added this line and it solved the problem: DirectoryIndex index.php

Answer (score 0):

Be aware the full URL does not work, only use the relative URL